# Concatenate a scalar with pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to concatenate the following two data set. Any help would be appreciated please.

1st data `total_pos`:

```
1170050176.9395077
```

2nd data `p`:

```
0    -0.000844
1    -0.002487
2    -0.004132
3    -0.006029
4    -0.004442
Length: 5, dtype: float64
```

The output i wish:

```
0    1170050176.9395077
1    -0.000844
2    -0.002487
3    -0.004132
4    -0.006029
5    -0.004442
Length: 6, dtype: float64
```

My code:

```
p = np.concatenate([total_pos,p])
```

The error:

```
   p = np.concatenate([total_pos,p])
  ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or using `numpy.hstack`:

```
arr = np.hstack([total_pos, s])
# or into series
s = pd.Series(np.hstack([total_pos, s]))
```

Output:

```
array([ 1.17005018e+09, -8.44000000e-04, -2.48700000e-03, -4.13200000e-03,
       -6.02900000e-03, -4.44200000e-03])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html) with convert scalar to one element `Series`:

```
p = pd.Series([total_pos]).append(p, ignore_index=True)
print (p)
0    1.170050e+09
1   -8.440000e-04
2   -2.487000e-03
3   -4.132000e-03
4   -6.029000e-03
5   -4.442000e-03
dtype: float64
```

Your solution working if convert scalar to one element list:

```
a = np.concatenate([[total_pos],p])
print (a)
[ 1.17005018e+09 -8.44000000e-04 -2.48700000e-03 -4.13200000e-03
 -6.02900000e-03 -4.44200000e-03]
```

For `Series` add constructor:

```
s = pd.Series(np.concatenate([[total_pos],p]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of the solutions they propose are based on [Series.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html): append an element to your series but it must be of the series type.

**First solution:** Proposed by [@jezreal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58197792/9302488), append ignoring the indexes, in this way the index of the new element is calculated automatically

**Second solution:** Please specify the value of the index:

```
s=pd.Series([11,22,33])
new_index = [str(s.index[-1] + 1) + 'b'] # you may need to specify a particular index for the new series, in this case calculate the value following the last index
s = s.append(pd.Series(44, index=new_index))

0     11
1     22
2     33
3b    44
```

If you want to transform the series used in a numpy array, just do:

```
arr = np.array(s)
# output: array([11, 22, 33, 44])
```

Comment: I didn't see your answer, I tagged you

Comment: No problem, I think it, so add comment